# Random 1-5 5x5 Array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, combinatorics

I am trying to make a 5x5 table that will have the numbers 1-5 random put in the rows/columns. But they need to have all different numbers for each row and column.

ex:
12345
54123
41532
35214
23451

The code I currently have is very long so I will give a pastebin link to it. http://pastebin.com/ex1bcLxh

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: What you want is a random [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Comment: I worked through this deceptively difficult problem years ago, and later had a friend tell me it was basically what he spent a semester doing at UVA in his combinatorics class. All that to say: it's a very rewarding problem to solve on your own if you have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with off the top of my head - I haven't bothered with optimisation because for the grid size of 5x5 mentioned in the question it feels instantaneous. (Testing in IE7 even 7x7 grids only take a couple of seconds. 8x8 is noticeably slower, sometimes slow enough to trigger the long-running script error.)

```
function createGrid(size) {
   var grid = [],
       row = [],
       x,y,t;

   for (x=size; x>0; x--)
      row.push(x);

   addRows:
   while (grid.length < size) {
      t = row.slice();
      row = [];
      while (t.length > 0)
         row.push(t.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length), 1)[0]);

      for (y=0; y<grid.length; y++)
         for (x=0; x<size; x++)
            if (row[x] === grid[y][x])
               continue addRows;

      grid.push(row);
   }

   return grid;   
}

var test = createGrid(5);
alert(test.join("\n"));
```

In case it's not obvious, the basic idea is to start off with a row [5,4,3,2,1]; shuffle the row and check if it can be added; repeat until done.

(I thought about starting by generating all potential rows and then randomly choosing from them, but that seemed like too much hassle given that I'm not very good with permutation algorithms - just doing a random shuffle each time seemed a lot less trouble.)

Comment: This will give me a good basis since I can't get it to print to an element. Thanks so much.

Comment: To output a really simple table with one line of code: `document.write("<table><tr><td>" + createGrid(5).join("</td></tr><tr><td>").replace(/,/g,"</td><td>") + "</td></tr></table>");` - of course, you may not want to use `document.write()`, indeed I don't really recommend it, but you get the idea of how easy it is to turn the array returned by the function into the appropriate HTML for a simple table element...though in practice you probably want to use something more civilised like a nested for loop that creates the `<td>` elements individually...

Answer (score 2):

There are 56 reduced [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) of order 5, enumerated [here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/reduced5.txt).  "Reduced" means that each of them has the top row and the leftmost column in sorted order.

You can apply any permutation to the rows, or to the columns, of a Latin square,
and the result will also be a Latin square.  It also follows that any Latin square can be converted to a reduced Latin square by:

1. permuting all n columns to put the top row in sorted order
2. permuting the bottom (n-1) rows to put the left column in sorted
   order.

(The top left element is already in its correct position after the first permutation, so there are only n-1 rather than n rows to sort in the second step.)

So by reversing this operation, we can start with one of the 56 reduced Latin squares,
and generate any of the 56*(5!)*(4!) = 161280 squares representing the complete set.

So:

1. Choose one of the 56 reduced order-5 Latin squares at random.
2. Choose one of the 4!=24 permutations of the bottom four rows at random, and apply it.
3. Choose one of the 5!=120 permutations of all five columns at random, and apply it.

Assuming uniformly distributed samples in steps 1-3, this process should yield uniformly distributed samples from the complete set of 161280 order-5 Latin squares.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is a difficult task, especially if you are concerned about having a uniform distribution among all Latin squares. (There's at least [one book](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291520-6610%281996%294:6%3C405%3a%3aAID-JCD3%3E3.0.CO;2-J/abstract) entirely devoted to this topic.) Here's pseudocode for one algorithm (not the most efficient, but will get the job done):

```
for each row {
   make an array of the integers 1..N
   repeat {
       make a random permutation of the array
   } while (array conficts with any previously assigned row)
   set row to array
}
```

(Array `a` "conflicts" with row `r` if `a[i] == r[i]` for some i in the row.) This assumes that you have code to randomly shuffle an array. Search the web for this if you don't have a shuffle algorithm handy.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335711/12048) pointed out, this is also known as a [Latin Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Latin squares are a class of [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, hence a solution can be found using [Knuth's Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X).

The [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) representation should not be too hard to code in Javascript.  I have implemented something similar in Lua.

The terminology may be confusing, because the algorithm description refers to a "matrix", "rows" and "columns", however these are not the same thing as the rows and columns of your (output) matrix.  Instead, the "rows" are candidate entries in your array (`a[1][2]=3` etc.) and the "columns" are patterns in which either one coordinate or the value is a wildcard, e.g. `a[Y][2]=3`, `a[1][X]=3`, `a[1][2]=V`.

To choose a random solution, you can randomly shuffle the list of entries before assigning them to the "rows" of the algorithm.  (In the case of the Dancing Links representation, the rows form a circularly-linked list, and you can insert the entries into this list in random order.)